# Can I make font loading in CSS Optional for mobile devices?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

My current Website-Design is built with the Bootstrap responsive framework. It uses several custom fonts, which make up about 50% of the document size. The fonts are included via CSS, the way of inclusion can not be changed.

My goal now is to stop mobile devices from requesting these fonts, in order to reduce their bandwidth consumption.

Is there a CSS way, like `@media (min-width: 480px)`, to not load the fonts in the responsive layout?

Comment: Of course, a "mobile device" may be using high-bandwidth wifi, and a 17" laptop could be using a tethered mobile connection. It's difficult to detect what sort of network connection your user has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most implementations, background images that are referenced in CSS media queries get pre-downloaded. (Unless you [do some fiddling](http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/) with your use of `display:none;`, but that won't be supported in all browsers.)

The same applies to any fonts you've included via media queries — even if they're specified for a larger/different viewport.*

Why?

This allows for a smoother transition if viewport size is changed, e.g. from portrait to landscape.

Solution?

Considering the constraints you mentioned, I don't see a clean way to do this only with CSS. You could do something with JS (but make sure it degrades gracefully), or [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14440853/1779823).

But the easiest ways to reduce [HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13808322/css-media-query-http-request) and how much your visitors have to download include doing one or all of the following:

- Using less fonts, or web-safe fonts instead.
- Using a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for fonts.
- Including 'minified' font files that only have the characters you'll
  be using them for.

Check out [Google Web Fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts) for the latter two.

If you expect or get a lot of mobile traffic that's important for the site, it's always worth re-thinking a website's design and markup from a mobile-first approach: what's necessary and what isn't. (That approach can often help to even reduce clutter on the desktop version of your site.)

---

<sup>* The [fiddling approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442397/1779823) could be useful for fonts too, but you'd have to do browser testing yourself, as so far it's undocumented.</sup>

Comment: you could look at using something like typekit as a javascript way to include the fonts and call it in using something like enquire.js

Comment: @ScottSimpson, thanks! I've updated my answer — feel free to make edits :)

Answer (score 1):

You could create two different stylesheets, one for mobile and one for desktop, then use PHP browser detection or various other methods to see if the user is on a mobile device or desktop device, and provide them with the corresponding stylesheet.

Take a look at the PHP `get_browser` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: I'd suggest that too (but browser sniffing can be inaccurate), but seems the question was specifically about CSS methods

Answer (score 1):

All background images aren't necessarily pre-downloaded if referenced in your media queries -

http://timkadlec.com/2012/04/media-query-asset-downloading-results/

perhaps this technique would also work for fonts too. Not if you're using anything that'd need JS (like typekit, google) your font's will be requested because of the JS anyways afaik.

Comment: Some really useful stuff in this article around prefetching and downloading too http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/front-end-performance-for-web-designers-and-front-end-developers/